# Problems referencing other project

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm trying to reference a library project from my working project in Flash Builder 4.6, however it's not working. When I try and import a class from the library project I get an error.

- **I have referenced the library project:**

[image: ReferencedProject]

- **I can see the class that I want to use in package explorer:**

[image: PackageExplorer]

- **But I can't import the class into my working project:**

[image: ImportError]

I've tried restarting the IDE, and have tried deleting AS3CoreLib and then creating it again. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you use 'com.adobe.*'? does the 'autopopulate' show any of the other classes? What happens if you do a 'clean' and then rebuild your project?

Comment: @ethrbunny no, autopopulate doesn't show anything past com.adobe.viewsource. www.Flextras.com has solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to add that project [or SWC] to your library path.  That is not the same as "Referenced projects".

I wrote a detailed blog post about [What to do with a SWC](https://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2009/12/18/What-do-you-do-with-a-SWC?event=PurchaseHistory).  Instead of the "Add SWC" button you can use the "Add Project" Button.

Comment: Thanks, this has solved the problem. I will start reading your blog :)